# Sorting not working in swimlane/ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable 11.2.0. I have a column with client side sorting. But that value of the column is determined by an evaluated expression,i..e.. The actual value of that column is some numbers(lat and long) but we have created a custom pipe which will call a google api to calculate the lat and long to convert to location. so the problem is sorting is not working on that column.

Comment: post some code?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your custom comparator method. It's hard to tell you exactly how to do it without seeing your code, but basically you can look at an example how to do it here:
[ngx-datatable-comparator](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/sorting/sorting-comparator.component.ts).

See the official API [here](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#comparator).